# My decryption in Perl is coming out all 0's

Tags: perl, encryption

The program in Perl encrypts fine but decryption is coming out all 0's. Why is this happening? I used the same method to encrypt/decrypt the string.

```
$string = "This is an encryption program";        # any length
$keystr = "948D5E5";                              # length <= 8

print "original  : ", $string, "\n";

$enc = hexcrypt($string, $keystr);
print "encrypted : ", $enc, "\n";

$dec = hexcrypt($enc, $keystr);
print "decrypted : ", $dec, "\n";

sub hexcrypt {
  my (@pac, $pacstr, $l, $pac, $pacenc, $format, $pacencstr);

  my @string    = split(//, @_[0]);               # the string to encrypt
  my $keystr    = @_[1];                          # the key
  my $key       = hex($keystr);                   # the key in binary
  my $keylength = length($keystr);
  my $encstr    = "";                             # accumulator for returned string

  do {
    @pac       = splice(@string, 0, $keylength);  # take out a packet of digits (or less at end)
    $pacstr    = join("", @pac);                  # into a string
    $l         = length($pacstr);
    $pac       = hex($pacstr);                    # convert to a 32-bit integer
    $pacenc    = $pac ^ ($key >> ($keylength * 4 - 4 * $l)); # shift key right if $l < $keylength, and   XOR
    $format    = "%0" . sprintf("%.d", $l) . "X"; # we want the leading zeros
    $pacencstr = sprintf($format, $pacenc);       # back into a string

    $encstr   .= $pacencstr;                      # add to encrypted string
  } while scalar @string > 0;

  return $encstr;
}
```

Comment: @Beth; Are you sure you are de-crypting, it looks like a second encryption pass.  And what Artjom said, there are some quoting and spacing issues with line 4 and 6.

Comment: That was another typo in line 4 & 6. If it's a 2nd encryption pass, why would it come up all 0's.

Comment: `$format = "%0" . sprintf("%.d", $l) . "X";` - shouldn't that be `$l * 2` ?

Comment: If you call `hex` on a variable, it is supposed to return text [0-9A-F], not binary or a number.

Comment: $1*2 in format changes the encrypt and the decrypt

Comment: To convert a string from a decimal value to a hexadecimal value, use sprintf and specify either %x (hexadecimal integer) or %lx (long hexadecimal integer)

Comment: @owlstead: *"If you call hex on a variable, it is supposed to return text [0-9A-F]"* No, `hex` converts a *hex string* to a *binary* number. For instance `hex 'f' == 15` is *true*.

Comment: @Borodin Ah, thanks, that's absolutely illogical but I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `$pacstr` is a chunk of the string to be encoded, with a length equal to or less than the length of the key.

Here, your key is `948D5E5` which is seven characters long, so the first value of `$pacstr` is the first seven characters of `$string`, which is `This is`.

So your statement

```
$pac = hex($pacstr)
```

is doing

```
$pax = hex('This is')
```

which returns zero because there are no valid hex digits in the string.

Surely you must have come across exhortations to `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of *every* Perl program? If you had followed this advice here you would have seen the following

```
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'T' ignored at E:\Perl\source\xmls.pl line 33.
Illegal hexadecimal digit ' ' ignored at E:\Perl\source\xmls.pl line 33.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'r' ignored at E:\Perl\source\xmls.pl line 33.
Illegal hexadecimal digit ' ' ignored at E:\Perl\source\xmls.pl line 33.
Illegal hexadecimal digit 'm' ignored at E:\Perl\source\xmls.pl line 33.
```

which is a *big* clue to the problem.